# Proving that gravitational binding energy is proportional to $\frac{GM^2}{R}$

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, dimensional-analysis, binding-energy

In the book "The Physics Of Stars" it is written that the gravitational binding energy stored in a sphere of radius $R$ and total mass $M$ is equal to $$-f\frac{GM^2}{R}$$

Where $f$ is some constant of proportionality

Also it is mentioned that a larger value of $f$ is obtained as density increases towards the center.

How can one prove both statements?

Comment: Dimensional analysis suffices for the first.

Comment: @G. Smith Dimensional analysis doesn't specify the equation, it only demonstrates how this equation results energy as we expect it. I'm looking for a general derivation.

Comment: Dimensional analysis uniquely specifies this expression for the gravitational energy.

Comment: @G. Smith. You could imagine adding an extra factor of M but divided by a product of some fundamental constant homogenous to a mass in principle. So I am not sure either dimensional analysis rigorously work in this example even though it would be a natural guess.

Comment: @StarBucK No. The theory of Newtonian gravity has *no* fundamental constant with the dimensions of mass.

Comment: @G. Smith. I am not saying it has. I am just saying that there are implicit assumptions in what you say. I dont know the exact context of his book and what has been explained before. But for the dimensional analysis to be a derivation you must know some further info about newtonian gravity. This is my point.

Comment: @G. Smith Let me rephrase first question: How can one derive the general expression for gravitational binding energy for any spherical isotropic mass distribution? Is dimensional analysis sufficient?

Comment: Dimensional analysis is sufficient to give the form you stated, but insufficient to give the numerical factor $f$. To get that, you have to integrate. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy#Derivation_for_a_uniform_sphere) does the integral for uniform density, in which case $f=3/5$.

Answer (score 1):

The binding energy can be calculated from the work needed to take shells of matter away from the star to infinity, until it's all gone (technically the negative of that).

If $\rho$ is the density, the radius of the star that's left is $r$ then the mass of the star that is left is $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\rho$, and the work needed to remove a shell of mass $4\pi r^2 \rho dr$ from $r$ to infinity is
$$G( \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\rho)\times (4 \pi r^2 \rho) \times \frac{1}{r} dr$$

integrate this from $0$ to $R$ and use $M=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3\rho$ and you should get the result.

$f$ would have to be larger if the density increases towards the middle as follows:

Imagine an extreme case where almost no matter was at the edge of the star, but nearly all within $\frac{R}{2}$ - it's like having a star of the same mass, but half the radius, so $-f\frac{GM^2}{R}$ changes to $-f\frac{GM^2}{R/2}$ or $-2f\frac{GM^2}{R}$, so it's as if the $f$ has increased.

Comment: For the first part, I have already tried this integral and I always end up at $\int r^4ρ^2 dr$ from 0 to R but going any more requires to specify the expression for density, is it possible to prove first statement in a way that does not require specific expression for density? I tried using integration by parts to get an integral which gives total mass, yet it was not successful

Comment: The answer has enough information for you to do it now.  Hint:  you won't need any difficult integrations

Comment: @sagittariusA *is it possible to prove first statement in a way that does not require specific expression for density?* Yes. De-dimensionalize the integral by writing $r=Ru$ and $\rho(r)=\rho_\text{av}g(u)$ where $\rho_\text{av}=M/(\frac43\pi R^3)$. You’ll get $GM^2/R$ times a dimensionless integral over $u$ from $0$ to $1$ involving the dimensionless density profile $g(u)$.